# Why the iBGP received network is not valid?

Tags: bgp, networking

I test the BGP in my PC, this below is the topology:

`R1--(eBGP)--R2--(iBGP)--R3`. and `R2-R3-R4` are in OSPF(omit details).

[image]

this is my detail configuration of BGP:

```
[R1-bgp]dis this
#
bgp 100
 peer 10.1.12.2 as-number 200
 #
 ipv4-family unicast
  undo synchronization
  network 100.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
  network 100.1.2.1 255.255.255.255
  peer 10.1.12.2 enable
#
return
```

```
[R2-bgp]dis this
#
bgp 200
 peer 3.3.3.3 as-number 200
 peer 3.3.3.3 connect-interface LoopBack0
 peer 10.1.12.1 as-number 100
 #
 ipv4-family unicast
  undo synchronization
  network 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
  network 10.1.23.0 255.255.255.0
  peer 3.3.3.3 enable
  peer 10.1.12.1 enable
#
return
```

```
[R3-bgp]dis this
#
bgp 200
 peer 2.2.2.2 as-number 200
 peer 2.2.2.2 connect-interface LoopBack0
 peer 4.4.4.4 as-number 200
 peer 4.4.4.4 connect-interface LoopBack0
 #
 ipv4-family unicast
  undo synchronization
  network 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255
  peer 2.2.2.2 enable
  peer 4.4.4.4 enable
#
return
```

I have a question, you see in R3, the `bgp routing-table`, the network `100.1.1.1/32` and `100.1.2.1/32` is not valid, so can not added into the `ip routing-table`. but why it is invalid?
and the same thing, in R1 there is no R3's `3.3.3.3` in `bgp routing-table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes received via eBGP and advertised to iBGP neighbors preserve original next hop information. To change that use the next-hop-self command when peering iBGP boundary routers with other iBGP routers, or add 10.1.12.0/30 into IGP.